# Turing machine that decides $A=\{0^{2^n} | n \ge 0 \}$ with an alphabet of two symbols

Tags: turing-machines

I need to build a turing machine that decides $A=\{0^{2^n} | n \ge 0 \}$ with an alphabet of two symbols - $\{0, \_ \}$.

I'm aware of the known TM that decides this language with three symbols $\{0, x, \_\}$ but I am not able to come up with one that does it with just two.

Any advice would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that $\_$ denotes the blank character. A strategy for the TM  you are looking for is the following:

1. Check if the input is a single $0$, if so accept.
2. Replace every other $0$ with $\_$. If, during this process, the number of encountered $0$s is odd, reject.
3. Pack all the $0$s together. This can be done as follows:

   1. Reset the head to the beginning of the tape (search for a $0$ preceded by two $\_$).
   2. Locate the last $0$ (i.e., the only one followed by two $\_$) and, in the process, remember if a $\_$ is encountered before it.
   3. If no $\_$ is encountered you are done. Otherwise continue.
   4. Replace the last $0$ with $\_$.
   5. Locate the first $0$ and write write $0$ before it.
   6. Repeat from step 3.2.
4. Repeat from step 1.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful.
I forgot to mention that I also need the TM to have 10 or less states (including accepting and rejecting states). In my attempts so far I was not able to go below 15.